# Cancel event while ItemAdding

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, event-receivers, discussion-board

I am just trying to cancel the default behavior of event when adding Item

```
 public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        try
        {
            //my code
            SPListItem parentItem = oList.GetItemById(discussionId);
            SPListItem reply =SPUtility.CreateNewDiscussionReply(parentItem);
            reply["Body"] = properties.AfterProperties["Body"];
            reply.Update();

            properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelNoError;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            properties.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
            properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError;
        }
        base.ItemAdding(properties);
    }
```

Still it fires the default behavior of `ItemAdding`. Is there anyway to to stop the default behaviour of code and to execute only my code. I just want my `reply` object to be created and the default object should not be added to list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to set

```
properties.Cancel = true;
```

Your final code will look like

```
public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    try
    {
        //my code
        SPListItem parentItem = oList.GetItemById(discussionId);
        SPListItem reply =SPUtility.CreateNewDiscussionReply(parentItem);
        reply["Body"] = properties.AfterProperties["Body"];
        reply.Update();

        properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelNoError;
        properties.Cancel = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        properties.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
        properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError;
    }
}
```

Comment: The tooltip says its obsolete use Status instead

Comment: Ok its because you are in SP2013. Try updated code.

Answer (score 1):

After removing this line and its worked for me:

```
base.ItemAdding(properties);
```

Comment: I came across the same problem. This answer actually is correct. It lacks a bit of explanation, but the downvote isn't justified. To extend the answer: `base.ItemAdding(properties)` resets the properties.Status to Continue. So either put the base call at top of the custom code, or remove the line to solve the issue.